# Block submit form for 2 field with invalid date

Tags: jquery, forms, date, submit, mask

i need some help to solve my problem. I've got 2 input field with a mask ( http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ ) like that > 12/2010 ( mm/yyyy ).

I want that user could register form when a date is valid or leave blank, and send an alert in a div when a date is invalid.

It's working fine if i've got 1 field, but when i have 2 field, if user enter a valid date in the second, he can register the form.

Else, if you have any idea to restrict end date that can be before the start date ...

Thanks for any help ;)

My HTML code :

```
<form id="blockdate">
<div>date start: <input class="date" type="text"></div>
<div>date end: <input class="date2" type="text"></div>
<div><input class="submit" type="submit"></div>
<div id="msg"></div>
</form>
```

My JS code :

```
        function verifyDate(datevalue) {

      var done = false;

      if(datevalue != null || datevalue != ''){
        var tmp = datevalue.split('/');
        var month = tmp[0];
        var year = tmp[1];

       if(month >= 1 && month <= 12){
       if(year >= 1990 && year <= 2099){
           clean();
           done = true;
          }
          else {
            $('#msg').html('Year invalid 1900 - 2099.');
          }
       } else {
          $('#msg').html('Month invalid');
       }     
    } if (datevalue < 1 ) {
        done = true;
    }

    return done;
  }
function verifyDate2(datevalue2) {

      var done = false;

      if(datevalue2 != null || datevalue2 != ''){
        var tmp = datevalue2.split('/');
        var month = tmp[0];
        var year = tmp[1];

       if(month >= 1 && month <= 12){
       if(year >= 1990 && year <= 2099){
           clean();
           done = true;
          }
          else {
            $('#msg').html('Year invalid 1900 - 2099.');
          }
       } else {
          $('#msg').html('Month invalid');
       }     
    } if (datevalue2 < 1 ) {
        done = true;
    }

    return done;
  }



  function clean() {
     $('#msg').html('');
  }

    jQuery(function($) {
     $(".date").mask("99/9999");   

       $('.blockdate').submit(function() {
          var datevalue = $('.date').val();
          var datevalue2 = $('.date2').val();
          return verifyDate(datevalue);
       });

       $(".date").change(function(){
        var datevalue = $(this).val();
          if(datevalue.length == 7) {
            verifyDate(datevalue);
          } else {
            clean();
          }
      });


    jQuery(function($) {
     $(".date2").mask("99/9999");   

       $('.blockdate').submit(function() {
          var datevalue2 = $('.date2').val();
          return verifyDate2(datevalue2);
       });

       $(".date2").change(function(){
        var datevalue2 = $(this).val();
          if(datevalue2.length == 7) {
            verifyDate2(datevalue2);
          } else {
            clean();
          }
      });

    });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can slightly simplify your task by providing a small regex.

```
`^([0]?\d|1[0-2])/(199\d|20\d{2})$`
```

use it this way

```
function TestDate(input) {
    var pattern = /^([0]?\d|1[0-2])\/(199\d|20\d{2})$/;
    return pattern.test(input);
}
```

It checkes weather the first part, i.e. lies between 1 and 12 and the second part between 1990 and 2099.

**EDIT**

After you have tested the correctness of the format you can see the range as follows

```
function RangeOk (lowerDate, upperDate) {
    return GetNumeric(lowerDate) < GetNumeric(upperDate);
}

function GetNumeric(input) {
    var parts = input.split("/");
    var yearNum = parseInt(parts[1]) * 12;
    // Get rid of leading 0 if exists
    // It can be there as the pattern above allows it.
    yearNum += parseInt(parts[0].replace(/0(\d)/, "$1"));
    return yearNum;
}
```

There is a small math trick.

Comment: Hello Oybek,

thanks for you explanation with regex, but i'm not familiar with JS and don't understand how i call this function ???

Many thanks

Comment: Replace your `verifyDate` function with `TestDate`

Comment: I'm not able to find the answer, i test different thing with your great code, but not able to find the solution.

I'm sorry to disturb you again ...

Comment: here is a clue for you try this `alert(TestDate("11/2010")); alert(TestDate("Wrong value")); alert(RangeOk("11/2010", "11/2011")); alert(RangeOk("11/2010", "11/2009"));`

Answer (score 1):

1. You could start out with disabling the submit button, until all formfields are valid, then enable it `$("submit").prop("disabled",true);`
2. On `$(input).blur()` check if both input values are valid.
3. Get both year values and compare them: `startdate <= enddate`
4. Enable the send-button

Enhancements:

`if(datevalue2 != null || datevalue2 != '')` => `||` should probably be `&&` => can be written as:`if(!datevalue2)`

```
var datevalue2 = $('.date2').val();
          return verifyDate2(datevalue2);
```

=> `return verifyDate2($('.date2').val())`

**EDIT:**

you only need one verify function, they are identical.

try this to prevent formsubmit on wrong inputs:

```
  if(year >= 1990 && year <= 2099){
       clean();
       done = true;
        $(".submit").prop("disabled",false);
      }

   else {
        $('#msg').html('Year invalid 1900 - 2099.');
        $(".submit").prop("disabled",true);
      }
   } else {
      $('#msg').html('Month invalid');
      $(".submit").prop("disabled",true);
   }
```

Comment: Hello Christoph,

thanks for your help, but i can't start with submit disabled, because user have the possibility to register form without write any date. 
It's my fault i did'nt say it in my message. 

Thanks :)

Comment: no problem, just leave that part out, in every case you should correct those ||.